# Importing only the flags which I'm using in my app (flag-icons library). How importing from CDN works?

Tags: performance, npm, size, bundle, tree-shaking

I've recently come across a way of importing font awesome icons which would allow the creation of a final bundle with only the icons in use [FontAwesome documentation](https://fontawesome.com/docs/apis/javascript/import-icons). I understand that the bundler (Vite in my case) applies tree shaking in order to create a smaller bundle.

I'm currently in the midst of developing an app that also uses flags. Thus I stumbled upon the following repository [Flag Icons](https://github.com/lipis/flag-icons). I've installed the npm package and added the stylesheet to index.html. Everything works as expected.

Does using the library this way mean I imported all the flags in my project, even the ones I won't use? Is there a way I can create a smaller bundle with the ones I'm going to use?

Comment: Any update on this one? I'm facing the same problem right now, I don't know how only to include the ones I need.

Comment: I haven't tried this myself but I see in their npm documentation that you could remove the countries you don't need from this file ./node_modules/flag-icons/less/flag-icons-list.less. This would probably build the project with only the flags you are using. In my case, the flags are dynamic based on user input so I would have to use all the flags to cover all scenarios.